# Intellij IDE - Remove folder when switching between GIT Branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Not sure if this is more a GIT or an IntelliJ question ...

I have a project coming from GIT. I created and pushed a new branch. On this new branch I have coupe of new directories. Now when I switched back to the original branch, where these directories are not yet present (remotely), I still see these folders locally in my project, but not as files under version control.

Is it possible for thoses folders to be deleted by default if they've never been comitted or pushed on the current checked-out branch?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side. What IDE version do you use? Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: @hublo As far as I understand you have red highlight on this files right? If yes there will be a present because there are locally in your project. You can click on project git -> revert and checkbox (delete local copies and of added files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You just need to write in console:

```
git clean -fd
```

This will clean all unmanaged files when you switch between branches.
But be careful, it can also delete your new files, if it wasn't added to current git branch.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. But I can think of three possible scenarios that can happen.

1. You said you have created and pushed a new branch, but have you stage and commit your new files/folders to your new branch? If not, those files will be there even after checking out any branch since they are not added to VCS. Check the file status by running command `git status`. 
   If that is the case, just switch back to your new branch and add/commit those files properly.
2. If the directories are empty, those will never be added to VCS (GIT). If you want to keep empty directories within your project, the common practice is adding an empty file called `.gitkeep` to each directory. If it is the case, switch back to your new branch, add `.gitkeep` files to each directory and commit.
3. If your directory or files listed in `.gitignore` file, those files will never be added to VCS (GIT).